# Iterm2 alt + backspace Like Linux

Tags: linux, zsh, iterm2, alt, backspace

I changed my job and now I have a Macbook for working I configured Iterm2 with zsh and almost everything is working, but certain shortcuts aren't, one of the most used by me every day "alt+backspace" to delete a word before a special character appears, I tried a lot of things with the Hexa code an so on, in most cases it is almost working, but it deletes the entire line

Example :

```
ls /tmp/file1
```

With alt+ backspace this will delete the complete text `/tmp/file1` while on Linux it will just delete `file1`

Is there some way to configure Iterm2 to have the same behaviour than in Linux for this shortcut ?

I tried things like this

https://jorge.fbarr.net/2018/06/08/iterm-and-altbackspace/

But it's not working as in Linux.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Are you using `zsh` in Linux? Pretty sure this is a `bash`-vs-`zsh` issue, not related to iTerm2 or your MacBook.

Comment: Hi @chepner yeah, I installed zsh using brew, in my personal computer I have zsh also, and almost the same config but I can't make it work, have you some clue ?

Comment: Not sure. I think it has something to do with how Readline and zle define a "word", but I don't think I've ever bothered looking into how you change either library's definition.

Comment: Q is related to ITerm, becase other terminall does not block ALT+BS, or OPT+BS.

Answer (score 1):

This is what helped me. Option key should send ESC+ sequences and all will work fine.

[image]

And I have no idea what is "normal"